# Count custom taxonomy terms in WooCommerce cart and multiply the cart total by the number

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom taxonomy for WooCommerce products, let's say the slug is `city`.

The goal of the code is to loop through the cart contents, and save the number of unique *city* taxonomy entries.

After that, the original price needs to be multiplied by the number of the counted all unique *city* taxonomies.

I managed to get to this code where it gets the taxonomy terms, but oblivious on what to do next:

```php
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
$product_id   = $cart_item['product_id'];
$term_names = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'city', array('fields' => 'names') );}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the cart total you can use the `woocommerce_calculated_total` filter hook

Then you can use [count()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php), which counts all elements in the array `$term_names` and add the result to the `$counter` variable

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_calculated_total( $total, $cart ) {
    // Initialize
    $counter = 0;
    
    // Iterating though each cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        // Product ID in cart
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];

        // Get terms
        $term_names = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'city', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );
        
        // Add to counter
        $counter += count( $term_names );
    }

    return $total * $counter;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', 'filter_woocommerce_calculated_total', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thank you 7uc1f3r ! This obviously works perfectly. :) It seems I misformulated the goal in my question.I'd need to multiply the shipping totals, not the cart totals by the number of taxonomies :/

Comment: @JureZadravec for the shipping totals, I believe you can use the `woocommerce_cart_shipping_total` filter **or** the `woocommerce_package_rates` filter hook, **depending on your needs**. If you can't figure it out with the hook(s) I recommended, you can always ask it a new question by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.